# Why isn't localStorage used instead of cookies? ( and in other cases as well )

Tags: javascript

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage) it is suppose to be more secure than cookies for storing persistent data on the client.

However, checking the `localStorage` of `facebook.com`, `twitter.com`, and `linkedin.com` I can see that it is not being used.

Oddly, `linkedin` does have the key ( in `localStorage` ) `8df` when logged in , but trying to access it throws an error.

Comment: probably because IE is still in existence--and why code things two times [you'll ultimately need a fallback method]?

Comment: The question is kind of vague.  They aren't using it because they don't need it.  People who need it, use it.

Comment: @Dennis: i think OPs point is they use cookies, but LS is supposed to be more secure. so why would you stick with an inferior method when a better one exists?

Comment: @Denni - question updated ...

Comment: @BradChristie newer versions of Internet Explorer supports local storage, according to w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: @Brad - Do you mean pre IE 8 - look here -> http://caniuse.com/#search=localStorage

Comment: @AndersonGreen: Please don't cite W3S--[ever](http://www.w3fools.com/). With that said, yes, as of Ie8+ it's supported. But, sadly, a lot of the internet still uses <IE8 (esp corporate). and guess how many people log on while they're working? (Know your demographic).

Comment: I find that disturbing - that IE can slow down adoption of new technology by years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess (hopes this qualifies has an answer)

Web Storage is compatible with most common browsers: http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage .

For things that don't need to transit with session: what probably happens is that cookies is most commonly known and easy to use. There are lots of companies with average skilled ppl, who will run away when confronted with things out of their confort zone.

Edit after [Python Fanboy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2639576/python-fanboy)'s answer (+1 from me): [read his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18423180/30433).

Comment: I'd definitely run away if my boss told me "Don't use new technology or advanced techniques even if it's the right tool for the job.  You'll scare off our averaged skilled employees."

Answer (score 4):

`localStorage` has this drawback which cookies doesn't have: it's stored values aren't sent automatically with all HTTP requests so without more implementation Your server won't know what's stored in browser's `localStorage`.

`localStorage` is supported in IE since IE8.

Comment: Drawback is a poor choice of words.  It's for storing things locally - that makes not being sent to the server part of functionality or security.

Comment: I don't see that as negative.  Only send them when you need them, not every time.  You could just as easily state that as a negative for cookies..."stored values are sent with all HTTP requests even when you don't need them"

Comment: @Python: Certainly that first-visit authentication couldn't benefit (which I think is what you're inferring by listing that piece of functionality) but there are certainly a lot of other subsets of usability (from each site) that would benefit from using lS. The question then becomes, is it worth implementing (and more importantly debugging).

Comment: You all are right! What I wanted to say is that `localStorage` would be far more useful (in context of regular websites) if there would be an ultra simple way to mark some stored locally content to be sent automatically to server (withour JS). If You could easily do this for session ID then cookies would be obsolete.

Comment: ...this could be built pretty easy by combining some localStorage and ajax functionality... call it something like ... `ajaxWithLocal()`

Answer (score 2):

> According to MDN it is suppose to be more secure than cookies for storing persistent data on the client.

Taking a quick look at Facebook's cookie, for example, I see things like userid, authentication tokens, presence indicator for chat, and window size.  (Not posting my cookie here for obvious reasons).

The feature that makes cookies "less secure" (cookies are sent with the HTTP request) is the feature they need in this case because it's part of their communication protocol.  Authentication tokens are useless if they aren't sent to the server for, well, authentication.

Simply put, they aren't using localStorage in this case because they aren't trying to store things locally.

Comment: They do need to store some of those things ( if not all ) locally.  That is the primary purpose of cookies.  Also, it's just as easy to store them in localStorage and send the same values in the ajax body request.

Comment: That's a secondary purpose of cookies.  The primary purpose is to add statefulness to HTTP.  See the RFC here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2109/rfc2109

Comment: A cookie is a file on the client.  That is its primary purpose.  statefullness is just a fancy word for persistent data.